# Why is my published game has lower resolution than the original build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, native, resolution

I made an Android game in Unity and the installed APK's graphics looked good, then I uploaded it to Google Play and downloaded it when it got published and it has a different resolution now. I only have one quality level in the 'Quality Settings' tab and I tried to change every option there and in the 'Graphics' and 'Player' settings as well but nothing worked. I thought the problem was the Samsung Game Launcher app as it automatically included the published game but not the test APK but removing the game from it didn't help.

Even the Splash Screen looks more pixelated in the published one.
[Original APK's splash logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YRLc.jpg)
[Published game's splash logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrWhC.jpg)

I couldn't find any solution to the problem at the online forums and I'm out of ideas so I'd appreciate any new thought.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problem, it was caused by the Samsung game optimizing service that automatically reduced the resolution of the installed games. I was able to override this through the Samsung 'Game Plugins' app with the 'Game Booster Plus' plugin. I still don't understand why Samsung uses Game Launcher by defult if you can't even set game quality properly with it but the problem is solved at least.